# iOS app with Qt?

Tags: ios, qt

I am thinking of developing an cross-platform app for iOS and Android using Qt.
Has anyone done this before?

My app consists of 3 things:

- a simple pedometer
- a webview to a simple website
- connection to Apple Health's API

I wan to know if this would be technically possible with Qt and if a simple app like this would be accepted into the appstore (I've heard of difficulties about publishing apps that are not coded natively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Qt;

> Clang, the compiler used for iOS applications, allows mixing C++ and Objective-C code. To enable this mode, suffix your source files with .c mm, and add them to OBJECTIVE_SOURCES instead of SOURCES in the .pro file. This makes it possible to use frameworks from Apple's iOS Developer Library in Qt applications. Most useful is perhaps the possibility for adding In-App Purchasing with the StoreKit framework.

With connecting to Apple Health's API you'd have to use Objective-C/Swift code. This is a code example mixing C++ and Objective-C https://github.com/richardmg/qtdd13_qmlapp

As to publishing apps that are not coded natively, Clang is the front-end and LLVM is the back-end that compiles C, C++, Objective-C and swift code. If the compiler compiles code written in those languages or if you're able to test run the app you wrote on the OS, there shouldn't be problems publishing them. Unless there are some issues such as security with your app. The only problem you might face is being able to use specific features of the OS in your app like Apple health kit API or in-app purchase API written in python or C++ or any language that can be used to write iOS/Android apps. In which case, you'd have to use their original API. There are apps in iOS/Android app stores that are not written in their native languages.

Comment: Ok, thanks Nana, if I have updates about the framework chosen or specific feature problems, I'll post an update.